# What does particles with asterisk superscript * mean, such as $Z^*$ or $W^*$, in decay production?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, notation

I can always find that in some articles the production of higgs decay written as "$\rm H\to {ZZ}^*\to 4l$", "$\rm H\to ZZ\to 4l$", "$\rm H\to Z\gamma^*\to\ldots$” What dose it mean when some particles with a superscript *? Such as “$\rm Z^*, W^*, \gamma^*, \ldots$". What’s the difference between them and "$\rm Z, W, \gamma$"?

Comment: possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=asterisk

Comment: Asterisk here means virtual, off mass shell by a lot.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. It is one I've wondered about several times and never gotten around to asking, and the answer is not what I had expected it to be.

Answer (score 6):

In this context, the asterisk refers to a virtual particle, one that is off shell.

A $\rm Z$ boson, for instance, has a mass of $\sim 91~\rm GeV$, while a Higgs boson has a mass of $\sim 125~\rm GeV$. A Higgs boson is less massive than two $\rm Z$ bosons, and so the decay $\rm H\to ZZ$ is not possible unless one of the particles is off shell.